# Exporting drivingDistance results in pgRoutingLayer on QGIS 2.2.0?

Tags: qgis, pgrouting

Using @Underdark's pgRoutingLayer extension, I built a routable network and tested it with Dijksatra function, which worked perfectly.

Trying the next step toward an isochrone map, I tried the drivingDistance function. I get a map of the points correctly answering the query but the "export" button is disabled and I didn't find a way to at least get a table indicating the travelling cost for each point. It's a bit frustrating knowing the data are somewhere around (shown as red crosses on the map) but not being able to get them!

I'm running QGIS 2.2.0 on a Windows 64 system, PostgreSQL 9.1, PostgGIS pg91x64-2.0.6-1 and re-installed the pgRouting Layer extension from the extension manager of QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, neither me nor Ko (who added all the more advanced pgRouting functions to the plugin) could figure out a way to support exporting the isochrones. You have to go back to writing SQL statements if you need the data.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will try to think about supporting this again.